# I want to assert text in ag grid rows with cypress but not able to get correct data format

Tags: jquery, cypress, ui-automation, chai

I want to search for an Apple and assert that if Apple appears at least one column in the row.

[image]

```
cy.get('[row-id] [role=\"grid\"]').each((item) => {
    expect(item.text()).to.have.text("Keyword")
```

**Failure Log**

```
expected { Object (userInvocationStack, specWindow, ...) } to have text Apple

You attempted to make a chai-jQuery assertion on an object that is neither a DOM object or a jQuery object.

The chai-jQuery assertion you used was:

  > text

The invalid subject you asserted on was:

  > SeanLandsmanAppleCarrot

To use chai-jQuery assertions your subject must be valid.

This can sometimes happen if a previous assertion changed the subject.
```

.text() method is returning value as single string and therefore assertion is failing. Is there a way I get value "Sean Landsman Apple Carrot" instead of "SeanLandsmanAppleCarrot"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***"I want to search for an Apple and assert that if Apple appears at least one column in the row"***

A column in row is a "cell", in the DOM it's a `span` with class "ag-cell", so this

```
cy.contains('span.ag-cell', 'Apple');   // Apple anywhere
```

will succeed if there is an "Apple" anywhere.

---

It's a bit hard to tell if that's what you want.
It could be that you want to check if there's an "Apple" in "Sean Landsman" row, in which case

```
cy.contains('span.ag-cell', 'Sean Landsman')  // find the name
  .parent('div.ag-row')                       // select the row
  .contains('Apple');                         // Apple in that row
```

---

But what if you want to check the whole row texts?

```
cy.contains('span.ag-cell', 'Sean Landsman')  // find the name
  .parent('div.ag-row')                       // select the row
  .find('span.ag-cell')                       // all the cells in that row
  .then(cells => {
    return [...cells].map(cell => cell.text())  // map them to their texts
  })
  .should('deep.eq', ['Sean Landsman', 'Apple', 'Carrot']);

  // or might be ['', 'Sean Landsman', 'Apple', 'Carrot'] since there's a checkbox
```